# How do I create a percentage column in a pandas groupby where there is also a count aggregation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Example data:

```
d = {'employee_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
     'country': ['us', 'ind','us', 'ind','us', 'ind','us', 'ind','us', 'ind'], 
     'type': ['employee', 'employee', 'employee', 'employee', 'contractor', 'consultant', 'employee', 'contractor', 'consultant', 'employee'],
     'product': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'] 
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.groupby(['country', 'type', 'product'])['employee_id'].agg('count')
```

This code yields this output:

```
country  type        product
ind      consultant  a          1
         contractor  b          1
         employee    a          2
                     b          1
us       consultant  b          1
         contractor  a          1
         employee    a          2
                     b          1
```

What I want to do is create an additional column alongside that count column that has a percentage of the subgroup. For example, in the example above, for india employees it would be 67%, 33%.

I saw some posts on using transform, but I'm not sure how that applies in this case because I am doing a count of an employee_id column instead of a numeric column.

I tried this, but it didn't give me quite what I wanted.

```
df.groupby(['country', 'type', 'product'])['employee_id'].agg(lambda x: x.count()/x.sum())
```